# URL Rewrite error in website configuration

Tags: asp.net, url-rewriting, aspdotnetstorefront

I am trying to configure a ASPDotNetStoreFront application on local machine , that was running perfectly on live server.

While trying to run it locally it is giving error

> `HTTP Error 500.52 - URL Rewrite Module Error.`

I have gone through many articles and forums but could not resolve the issue. I am using windows 7, IIS7 and  Target framework is 3.5 and AspDotNetStoreFront version is 9.1.0.1

Error message screen shot is given below

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is because the sub virtual directory inherit the setting from parent node(the site root here).  So there will be duplicated rewrite rules in the virtual directory. You can disable the inheritance by using the following element:

```
<location path="." inheritInChildApplications="false">
<system.webserver>
 ...
<system.webserver>
</location>
```

However, point the site and virtual directory to the same physical path is not recommended. In this way, any configurations changes in site will be replicated to virtual directory. Obviously, changes on virtual directory also will be replicated to site.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest not using the default website or localhost as a binding and use staging.aspdotnetstorefront.[yourdomainhere].local or similar. Afterwards you can modify your hosts file by adding 127.0.0.1 staging.aspdotnetstorefront.[yourdomainhere].local for a loop back. This way there are no settings to inherit.

If you do need localhost for license reasons, you could always change the port on the binding (IE localhost:88).

I should also mention that you may need to modify your solution (if you are using the source) to have the web project point to the updated binding.